# Powershell search file based on hour and minutes?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script selecting files created between certain hours as below

```
if ($a.CreationTime      -gt (get-date).date -and 
    $a.CreationTime.Hour -ge 14 -and 
    $a.CreationTime.Hour -le 15){...}
```

This will pickup files from the current day and between `2PM` and `3PM`.

Now I want to change the time range to between `1:30 PM` and `3:30 PM`, How can I handle the minutes in my script?

Comment: Check `$a.CreationTime.TimeOfDay.TotalHours` as a decimal (13.5,15.5)

Comment: This is the one. please move to the answer, I will accept this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `$a.CreationTime.TimeOfDay.TotalHours` as a decimal (13.5,15.5)

```
if ($a.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).Date -and 
    $a.CreationTime.TimeOfDay.TotalHours -ge 13.5 -and 
    $a.CreationTime.TimeOfDay.TotalHours -le 15.5){...}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a mouthful but couldn't you use:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object{
    switch ($_.CreationTime.Hour){
        #creation hour is 1, check if minutes are over 30
        1 { if ($_.CreationTime.Minute -ge 30){ Write-Host $_; break} }
        #since hour is 2, no other check needed
        2 { Write-Host $_; break}
        #creation hour is 3, check if minutes is under 30
        3 { if ($_.CreationTime.Minute-le 30){ Write-Host $_; break } }
        #hour isn't 1,2 or 3 so do nothing
        default {break}
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an error with my code, I have corrected it to be minutes instead of hour

Comment: AFAIK the Hour is in 24h format, so switch 1=>13, 2=>14, 3=>15